# How do you determine the handedness of the polarization vector of a beam of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, mathematics

The Wikipedia page on circular polarization says,

> [For] polarization [as] defined from the point of view of the source...left- or right-handedness is determined by pointing one's left or right thumb away from the source, in the same direction that the wave is propagating, and matching the curling of one's fingers to the direction of the temporal rotation of the field at a given point in space. When determining if the wave is clockwise or anti-clockwise circularly polarized, one again takes the point of view of the source, and while looking away from the source and in the same direction of the wave's propagation, one observes the direction of the field's spatial rotation.

What I don't get is,

1. How do I even know what the direction of wave propagation *is* if I only have an expression for the E field and not the B field?  I know it's perpendicular to the E field but there are two ways for that to be true.
2. Even if I know the direction of propagation and so I apply the RHR to the cross product of the wave propagation vector and the E field vector (which seems to be what the Wiki quote is describing), that would just give me the direction the crossproduct would point in -- how does that then translate into CW or CCW rotation?

Comment: "_apply the RHR to the cross product of the wave propagation vector_" This seems unnecessary. The wave vector $\bf k$ already points in the direction of propagation (in vacuum or at least isotropic medium). This means you can already use the RHR to find it's direction of polarization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I even know what the direction of wave propagation is if I only have an expression for the E field and not the B field?

If you have, say,
$$\vec{E} = \hat{x}E_0 \cos\left(\omega t - kz\right)$$
you can ignore all the prefactors and just look at the argument of the cosine. If $t$ increases, then to stay at the same point on the wave, $z$ must also increase. Therefore we have a wave propagating in the $+z$ direction.

A wave propagating the other way would have $\ldots\cos\left(\omega t + kz\right)$

If you are working in exponential notation, then it's the same. Ignore the pre-factors and just focus on the exponent in $\hat{x}E_0 e^{i(\omega t \pm kz)}$.

> .. how does that then translate into CW or CCW rotation?

In a circularly polarized wave you're going to have something like

$$\vec{E} = \hat{x}E_0 \cos\left(\omega t - kz\right) + \hat{y}E_0 \cos\left(\omega t - kz \pm \pi/2\right)$$

If the $\hat{y}$ component is lagging the $\hat{x}$ component you have a RHC polarization, and if the $\hat{y}$ component is leading you have LHC polarization.

> I apply the RHR to the cross product of the wave propagation vector and the E field vector (which seems to be what the Wiki quote is describing)

I think you're misunderstanding this.

The "temporal rotation of the field" is not the same as the field vector itself.

Visualize the E vector spinning around the axis of propagation. Your fingers should follow that spin (with your thumb pointed along the axis). That's not the same as taking the cross product of the E field (at some specific point in time) and the propagation direction.

If you can do this with your right hand, it's RHC polarization, and if you can do it with your left hand it's LHC polarization.